# Converting data in byte format to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an output in the below bytes format. I would like to convert it to a Pandas Dataframe.

Actual Data

```
b'{"code":200,"data":{"facilities":[
  {"ref_id":"101","ref_name":"Product A","features":{"features1":"32","features2":"82"}},
  {"ref_id":"102","ref_name":"Product B","features":{"features1":"40","features2":"74"}},
  {"ref_id":"103","ref_name":"Product C","features":{"features1":"33","features2":"84"}},
  {"ref_id":"104","ref_name":"Product D","features":{"features1":"36","features2":"115"}},
  {"ref_id":"105","ref_name":"Product E","features":{"features1":"32","features2":"95"}},
  {"ref_id":"106","ref_name":"Product F","features":{"features1":"35","features2":"89"}},
  {"ref_id":"107","ref_name":"Product G","features":{"features1":"38","features2":"90"}}]},"request_id":"090"}'
```

Expected output (Dataframe):

```
ref_id, ref_name, features1, features2
101, Product A, 32, 82
102, Product B, 40, 74
103, Product C, 33, 84
104, Product D, 36, 115
105, Product E, 32, 95
106, Product F, 35, 89
107, Product G, 38, 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `json` and `pd.json_normalize`:

```
import json

# parse json to a dictionary
data = json.loads(s)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['data','facilities'])
```

Output:

```
  ref_id   ref_name features.features1 features.features2
0    101  Product A                 32                 82
1    102  Product B                 40                 74
2    103  Product C                 33                 84
3    104  Product D                 36                115
4    105  Product E                 32                 95
5    106  Product F                 35                 89
6    107  Product G                 38                 90
```